# Django REST auth_user (token generation)

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I am currently working on a project and encountered the following dilemma:

I work in Django REST and for the user I used the built-in model of Django REST and the auth_user table (I did not create the model) -  to generate the token I use the TokenObtainPairView view.

I noticed that the token will not be generated for me when I add the user manually to the database, but will only be generated when for the user who is added through the terminal in VSC via the createsuperuser command.

Is there a possibility to leave this like this and still be able to add a new user, because I think I will have the task of creating a post API in order to add a user to the database - now I don't know if this will be possible with how I started working ?